# Intel register naming

Tags: architecture, intel

I am puzzled about the register naming in intel architectures. Some sources present them as `rax`, for example, while other sources, including the dissasembly from objdump, as `%rax`. What is the meaning of that percent sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [two major syntax forms for x86 assembly language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax) - Intel and AT&T, and percent sign indicates AT&T one, which is historically used in unix universe.

It's not only about naming. Operation arguments direction is reversed, addressing is a little different, and some other things.